# Compare relationship data with parent data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have these models and their corresponding tables in the database:

- Order
- ConstructionSite
- WorkingHours

An Order `hasOne` ConstructionSite which in turn `hasMany` WorkingHours.

In my table `orders` I have a column `installation_planned_in_hours` and in my table `working_hours` I have a column `worked_hours`.

What is the best and more efficient way to retrieve all Orders which total of `worked_hours` (remember Order->ConstructionSite->WorkingHours) is at least 80% of the `installation_planned_in_hours`?

---

**EDIT 1:**

Practical example:

```
Order:
- id => 10001
- installation_planned_in_hours => 100

ConstructionSite:
- id => 1
- order_id => 10001

WorkingHours:
- id => 1
- construction_site_id => 1
- worked_hours => 5

- id => 2
- construction_site_id => 1
- worked_hours => 7

- id => 3
- construction_site_id => 1
- worked_hours => 8
```

Knowing that my Models have these relationships:

```
class Order extends Model
{
  public function constructionSite()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ConstructionSite');
  }
}

class ConstructionSite extends Model
{
  public function order()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
  }

  public function workingHours()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\WorkingHours');
  }
}

class WorkingHours extends Model
{
  public function constructionSite()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ConstructionSite');
  }
}
```

So how can I efficiently check if the `worked_hours` of the ConstructionSite associated with a specific Order are higher or lower of the 80% of the order's `installation_planned_in_hours`?

More precisely lets say I have more entries in my database (more orders, construction sites and working hours). How can I perform something like this:

```
$orders = Order::where('sum(constructionSite.workingHours.worked_hours)', '>', '80% of installation_planned_in_hours')->get();
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've come up with this solution:

```
$orders = \App\Order::with('constructionSite.workingHours')->has('constructionSite.workingHours')
  ->leftJoin('construction_sites', 'construction_sites.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
  ->select('orders.*', 'construction_sites.*', 'construction_sites.id as csid')
  ->leftJoin('working_hours', 'working_hours.construction_site_id', '=', 'construction_sites.id')
  ->selectRaw('sum(working_hours.worked_hours) as tot_whs')
  ->groupBy('working_hours.construction_site_id')
  ->havingRaw('sum(working_hours.worked_hours) > orders.installation_planned_in_hours * 0.8')
  ->get();
```

But is it really the nicest and more efficient way?

Comment: Can you add your models (code) to your question? And example of output .

Comment: @Jonjie I've added more info, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function workingHours()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(WorkingHours::class, ConstructionSite::class);
    }
}

$orders = Order::whereHas('workingHours', function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(worked_hours) total'))
        ->having('total', '>', DB::raw('0.8 * installation_planned_in_hours'));
})->get();
```